# Estrutura aninhada dando erro

Tags: python, if, else

Estou tentando criar um script que leia se a pessoa é maior ou menor de idade. Eu gostaria que se por exemplo apenas 1 pessoa for de maior, ela escreva '1 pessoa' e não '1 pessoas', mas meu código tá dando algum erro se todas as pessoas forem de menor ou de maior, mas funciona se eu mesclar. O que pode ser?

```
from datetime import date
atual = date.today().year
maior = menor = cont = 0
for nasc in range(1, 4):
    cont += 1
    nasc = int(input(f'Ano de nascimento da {cont}ª pessoa:'))
    idade = atual - nasc


    if idade >= 18:
        maior += 1
        if maior != 1:
            p1 = 'pessoas'
        else:
            p1 = 'pessoa'
    else:
        menor += 1
        if menor != 1:
            p2 = 'pessoas'
        else:
            p2 = 'pessoa'

print(f'{maior} {p1} de maior e {menor} {p2} de menor')
```

Comment: Se todas as pessoas forem maiores que 18 anos (ou menores) não ocorrerá qualquer atribuição à variável p2 (ou p1) mas você considera tais variáveis no print. Assim como inicializou as variáveis maior, menor e cont inicialize também as variáveis p1 e p2.

Comment: Na verdade não precisa dessas variáveis p1 e p2: https://ideone.com/epxCR0

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Simplifique a lógica, lembre-se que saber se é "pessoa" ou "pessoas" durante o laço é irrelevante já que esta informação mudará a cada execução do laço `for`.

É uma informação que só interessa na hora da impressão da mensagem, logo...

```py
from datetime import date

atual = date.today().year
maior = menor = 0

for cont in range(1, 4):
    nasc = int(input(f'Ano de nascimento da {cont}ª pessoa:'))
    idade = atual - nasc

    if idade >= 18:
        maior += 1
    else:
        menor += 1

p1 = "pessoa" if maior==1 else "pessoas"
p2 = "pessoa" if menor==1 else "pessoas"

print(f'{maior} {p1} de maior e {menor} {p2} de menor')
```

Esta estrutura, o `p1 = ... if ... else ...` é o ternário do Python e faz a mesma coisa que um...

```py
if maior == 1:
    p1 = "pessoa"
else
    p1 = "pessoas"
```

Só que ocupando apenas uma linha. :-)

Ah, lembre-se que dizemos 0 pessoas e não 0 pessoa!